# How can I download an application from the Mac App Store which is not compatible with my OS X version?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

Is there any way to download app from the Mac App Store which requires a more current OS X version than I have running on my Mac? I know it will not run, but I need the actual file.

Comment: No, would be the answer, no matter what app it is.

Comment: Ok, then do you know of a place where I can download `Install OS X Yosemite.app`? I just need the files.

Comment: No, there is no official source to download it other than the Mac App Store.